# What's the reason int32 const cannot be cast to uint32 when variables can?

Tags: go

I've found that you can cast a variable int32 to uint32 but you cannot cast a const int32 to uint32.

See here: https://play.golang.org/p/tDm6B6g5P6u

If line 14 is commented out it works.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add the behaviour is the same with int64 to uint64 and int to uint

Comment: The most technically correct reason is because Go doesn't support type casting at all.  The real question you mean to ask is probably "Why can't I convert an int32 to a uint32?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `uint32(ci)` is a constant expression. The [spec says this about constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions):

> The values of typed constants must always be accurately representable as values of the constant type.

A `uint32` cannot accurately represent the negative value `ci`, therefore this expression results in a compilation error.

Positive values in range are supported. For example, `uint32(-ci)` compiles with no error.

The expressions `uint32(vi)` and  `uint32(vc)` are [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).  Conversions betweeen numeric types are allowed, even when there's loss of accuracy.

Comment: However just to add you can cast it if your value is a positive number, see https://play.golang.org/p/ZlUYXCWYx0r - as long as it can be represented accurately that's fine.